# remove specific value that appear in the whole data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the df where in many rows and columns '-1' appears which is wrong data.
I was trying to remove by column:

df.drop(df[df['region'] == -1].index)

But wonder if there is way to do that for the whole df at once?

Comment: To be clear, Do you want to remove columns that has the value '-1' ?

Comment: df = df[~df['region'] == -1]

Comment: I want to remove rows that have that value in cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
```

To remove rows with -1

```
df = df.replace(-1, np.nan).dropna(axis=0)
```

To remove columns with -1

```
df = df.replace(-1, np.nan).dropna(axis=1)
```

To remove rows with -1 in the `region` column

```
df = df.replace(-1, np.nan).dropna(axis=0, subset=['region'])
```

Comment: what is that 'np.nan' ?  getting error np is not recognized?

Comment: np.nan means is used to indicate missing value , please ' import numpy as np ' to remove the error. Or please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df = df[df["region"] != -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the common way is to use pandas.dropna(). If "-1" only appears when the cell values is wrong you can first replace the '-1' value with np.nan:

```
df = df.replace(-1, np.nan)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0)
```

Axis = 0 for dropping all the rows containing '-1', this is the default parameter for the function.

Check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html